# How do I enter the value inside ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple question on angularjs

I want to put the value in target in dt asin

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="dt = '{{target}}'"> >>{{target}}</button>
```

The `{{target}}` prints the value correctly.. How do I enter the value in **dt inside ng-click**?

Comment: not cleared your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ng-click="dt = target"
```